# customize friend invite in as3

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-as3-api

I want to build a customize friend invite inside my flash application.
I don't want to use the Facebook ui box.

Any idea what is the best solution for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to do a custom graphic and then take all the user's friends.
Then you have to use as3 to select friends and save it into an array.
At the end you have to do the final call to Facebook to invite all the selected friends.